# Profit from a decline in a sector

Tags: stocks, investment-strategies, put-options

I know that put options are "safest" bet when anticipating a stock to decline.

But what of a sector, say energy, to decline over a long period of time (> 1 year). Are there additional options available?

Look for a bear ETF for that specific sector?

Note this will be "fun" money - not 401k or IRA!

Answer (score 1):

Many optionable stocks offer LEAPs which sometimes go out as far as two years.  You can find a list of them at the CBOE.com or Google "Symbol Directory LEAP CBOE".  I'd be hesitant to buy a furthest expiration because if your timing is off, you're paying top dollar.

There are a number of inverse energy ETFs.  You can find a list of them at ETF.DB.com

Answer (score 1):

The XLE options trade for Jan 2020, but id you look at the premiums, it might be tough. The $70 strike put was last traded at $4.40, you would need a drop to $65 just to break even. Tough to make money that way.

Comment: If I did the math right that's about a 12.5% drop. Not unreasonable if there's a full-market crash (or even a heavy correction) but yeah, I certainly wouldn't put that kind of money on it.

Comment: To break even, far more to make a decent return. On call spreads I look to make 5X for a 30% move over 12-18 months.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - You were discussing a long put and now it's making 5X on a call spread from a 30% move?  5X  on a bear call spread's credit?  I don't follow.

Comment: I offered that for sake of comparison. I had no personal experience buying puts or put spreads. Sorry if my comment confused the issue.